# Garbled screen after return from suspend 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, nouveau

Configuration: Asus motherboard m2n68 w/onboard Nvidia Geoforce 7025 and nforce630a chipset.

I've tried the Nouveau driver, and Nvidia 304,173. Everything works great with Nvidia except return from suspend. Nouveau gives intermittent problems with screen breaking up.

This has been a problem for the past several Ubuntu releases.

Any thoughts---Thanks